# Error: Invalid postback or callback argument

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, button, gridview

I am getting the following error on a button click with gridview

```
 Server Error in '/' Application.
Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using <pages enableEventValidation="true"/> in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using <pages enableEventValidation="true"/> in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:


[ArgumentException: Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using <pages enableEventValidation="true"/> in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.]
   System.Web.UI.ClientScriptManager.ValidateEvent(String uniqueId, String argument) +144
   System.Web.UI.Control.ValidateEvent(String uniqueID, String eventArgument) +111
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +29
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +35
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1724


Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.17929
```

It occurs when I press a button inside the gridview, and the odd thing is that I have another gridview, also with custom button in a column that runs different code, but gives no errors. Below is the code for the page and the codebehind.

```
namespace CCCC
{
    public partial class drivermangement : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
    {

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                if (Roles.IsUserInRole("Administrator"))
                {
                    LoggedInUser.Value = Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["driver"]);
                }
                else
                {
                    LoggedInUser.Value = Membership.GetUser().UserName.ToString();
                }
                DayOfTheWeekHiddenField.Value = Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["dow"]);
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Redirect("default.aspx");
            }
            if (NewCustomersGrid.Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                NewCustomersLabel.Visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                NewCustomersLabel.Visible = true;
            }
            if (NeedCompostGrid.Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                NeedCompostLabel.Visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                NeedCompostLabel.Visible = true;
            }
            if (CanceledGrid.Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                CanceledLabel.Visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                CanceledLabel.Visible = true;
            }
            if (VacationGrid.Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                VacationLabel.Visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                VacationLabel.Visible = true;
            }
            if (NewCustomersGrid0.Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                NewCustomersLabel0.Visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                NewCustomersLabel0.Visible = true;
            }
            if (NeedCompostGrid0.Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                NeedCompostLabel0.Visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                NeedCompostLabel0.Visible = true;
            }
            if (CanceledGrid0.Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                CanceledLabel0.Visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                CanceledLabel0.Visible = true;
            }
        }

        protected void NewCustomerDoneButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int CustomerID = Convert.ToInt32(((Button)sender).CommandArgument);
            string CustomerBinNeedAcknowledged = "Yes";
            string strConnString = "Data Source";
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Customers SET CustomerBinNeedAcknowledged=@CustomerBinNeedAcknowledged WHERE CustomerID=@CustomerID";
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerBinNeedAcknowledged", CustomerBinNeedAcknowledged);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerId", CustomerID);
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                }
            } 
       }
```

and the actual page:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="CCCCCC.drivermangement" CodeBehind="drivermangement.master.cs" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <asp:HiddenField ID="LoggedInUser" runat="server" />
    <asp:HiddenField ID="DayOfTheWeekHiddenField" runat="server" />
    <ajaxToolkit:TabContainer ID="RoutingTabs" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="0" 
        Width="900px">
        <ajaxToolkit:TabPanel runat="server" HeaderText="Pre-Route" ID="PreRouteTab">
        <ContentTemplate>
<br />
<asp:Label ID="NewCustomersLabel" runat="server" 
        style="font-weight: 700; font-size: large; color: #009933" Text="New Customers"></asp:Label>

<asp:GridView ID="NewCustomersGrid" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" 
        BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" 
        DataKeyNames="CustomerId" DataSourceID="NewCustomers" ForeColor="Black" 
        GridLines="Vertical">
<AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#99FF99" ></AlternatingRowStyle>
<Columns>
<asp:BoundField DataField="CustomerFullName" HeaderText="Name" 
                SortExpression="CustomerFullName" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="CustomerFullAddress" HeaderText="Address" 
                SortExpression="CustomerFullAddress" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="CustomerNeedsBin" HeaderText="Needs Bin?" 
        SortExpression="CustomerNeedsBin" />
<asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False"><ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="NewCustomerDoneButton" runat="server" CommandName="" 
                Text="Done" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("CustomerID") %>' OnClick="NewCustomerDoneButton_Click" CausesValidation="False" />

</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="NewCustomers" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:tcc_customersConnectionString %>" 

                SelectCommand="SELECT [CustomerId], [CustomerStatus], [CustomerFullName], [CompanyName], [CustomerFullAddress], [CustomerPickUpDay], [CustomerPickUpDay2], [CustomerDriver], [CustomerNeedsBin], [CustomerBinNeedAcknowledged] FROM [Customers] WHERE (([CustomerBinNeedAcknowledged] = @CustomerBinNeedAcknowledged) AND ([CustomerNeedsBin] = @CustomerNeedsBin) AND ([CustomerDriver] = @CustomerDriver) AND ([CustomerStatus] = @CustomerStatus) AND ([CustomerPickUpDay] = @CustomerPickUpDay OR [CustomerPickUpDay2] = @CustomerPickUpDay2))"><SelectParameters>
<asp:Parameter DefaultValue="No" Name="CustomerBinNeedAcknowledged" Type="String" />
<asp:Parameter DefaultValue="Yes" Name="CustomerNeedsBin" Type="String" />
<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="LoggedInUser" Name="CustomerDriver" 
            PropertyName="Value" Type="String"></asp:ControlParameter>
<asp:Parameter DefaultValue="New" Name="CustomerStatus" Type="String" />
<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DayOfTheWeekHiddenField" Name="CustomerPickUpDay" 
                PropertyName="Value" Type="String" ></asp:ControlParameter>
<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DayOfTheWeekHiddenField" 
            Name="CustomerPickUpDay2" PropertyName="Value" Type="String" />
</SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>

</ContentTemplate>

</ajaxToolkit:TabPanel>
        <ajaxToolkit:TabPanel runat="server" HeaderText="Post-Route" ID="PostRouteTab"><ContentTemplate>
```

I'm now wondering, does this have anything to do with the fact that the `GridView` is inside an `Ajax Tab Container`? Cause my other table that works fine is not...

Note: had to cut some code from page due to character limits

Comment: Forgot to note, I don't want to disable the eventvalidation. It only kind of solves the problem (proceeds, but view is not updated) and leaves me vulnerable to attack since it is a security measure

Comment: Please share only relevant code bits; that is probably the reason for your down votes

Comment: are you using update panels? are you adding data to the grid dynamically?

Comment: @NoviceProgrammerThanks, I'll edit it in a bit. I was wondering what was going on... And no update panels, just Ajax Tab Container and the grid is databound to my sql server

Comment: @NoviceProgrammer Re-edited, now just has what is related to the button, its gridview, and the page load

Answer (score 19, accepted):

1) Invalid Postback or Callback argument in GridView Problem may be: You are binding data in Page_Load event with either Object Data Source or Manual Binding with function call. This will make your GridView bind data on every event fire of any control.

When you are firing any GridView command with OnRowCommand, before RowCommand fire your GridView will rebind and all control within it will be assigned to new id. So RowCommand could not get the item which have fired the event.

Solution for Invalid Postback or Callback argument in GridView: You can bind your data within this if condition

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    //Your code for Bind data 
}
```

This code will definitely give you solution if this not work then check whether any other control is not giving error.

Comment: For more visit  

http://www.aspnetajaxtutorials.com/2007/10/invalid-postback-or-callback-argument.html


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        //your code here
    }
}

Even if it does not work go for this link

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carloc/archive/2008/05/02/invalid-postback-or-callback-argument-in-asp-net.aspx

Answer (score 1):

are you updating the Grid or any such control through javascript or Ajax.

If this is the case then you might face this. Possible solution can be to set EnableEventValidation to false.

Comment: Nope. None of that and I don't want to set EnableEventValidation to false for security reasons

Answer (score 0):

A few things to try

1. In your `Page Load` event, add a check for `!Page.IsPostBack` and move the non-authenticating code block there.
2. Experiment using a `LinkButton` instead of a regular button.

Answer (score 0):

This could be because of any third party controls you are using.

I also had this error. In my case i have a repeater control inside updatepanel and inside repeater control i was using telerik datepicker control. It was working fine in IE but not in mozilla and chrome. I examined the form data in both the cases by sending request from chrome and IE and found that the triggring control values are slightly different. i used telerik RadAjaxmanager instead of updatepanel the error gone.

Answer (score 0):

I testing all above solutions and other posts but my problem isn't done.

My problem was solved when cancel event at end of grid event at server side.

**This type of problem occurred when we using edit event of gridview.
just add e.Cancel = true; at the end of event.**

```
protected void grdEducation_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
  // do your processing ... 

  // at end     
  e.Cancel = true;
}
```