# Asp.Net : Redirect to another page from usercontrol in update panel

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

i have an update panel with a menu in it.
i wanna to redirect to another page when the user click on the print button in grid view in user control (in my update panel)
i used these codes,but they didn't work for me:

```
1 : Response.Redirect("PrintTicket.aspx");
2 : Response.Write("<script>window.open('PrintTicket.aspx','_parent');</script>");
3 : Page.Response.Redirect("PrintTicket.aspx", true);
4 : Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "ClientScript", "<script     language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>window.location.replace('http://vinaticket.ir    /PrintTicket.aspx');</script> ", false);
5 : ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(),     "redirect","window.location='" + Request.ApplicationPath + "PrintTicket.aspx';", true);
6 : Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "ClientScript", "<script     language='javascript' type='text/javascript'> postRefId('" + Session["TicketID"].ToString() +     "');</script> ", false);
7 : ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "redir", "document.location = 'PrintTicket.aspx'", true);
```

this is my code :

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="true"     UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate>
----menu .... with exit button
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server" ViewStateMode="Enabled">

    </asp:PlaceHolder>

</ContentTemplate>
<Triggers>
    <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="exit" />
</Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
//code behind to loade user control
private string LastLoadedControl
{
    get
    {
        return ViewState["LastLoaded"] as string;
    }
    set
    {
        ViewState["LastLoaded"] = value;
    }
}

private void LoadUserControl()
{
    try
    {
        string controlPath = LastLoadedControl;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(controlPath))
        {
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Clear();
            UserControl uc = (UserControl)LoadControl(controlPath);
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(uc);
        }
    }  
    catch (Exception ex) { }
}
```

my menu button :

```
protected void your_ticket_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Session["pg"] = "Z_ViewTicket.ascx";
            setPath();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { }
    }
    and set path method():
```

protected void setPath()
{
    try
    {
        string controlPath = string.Empty;
        controlPath = BASE_PATH + Session["pg"].ToString();
        LastLoadedControl = controlPath;
        LoadUserControl();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { }
}

> **Note:** i test a sample code and i find the reason, in my sample code i drag user control to my update panel and the button worked, but
>   when i call user control by these codes the button doesn't work(in
>   case one the user control register to main page but in case two there
>   isn't any register code in main page)

and for this problem **how can i redirect to other page?**

Comment: When in the page lifecycle do you invoke these? Did you try [RegisterClientScriptBlock()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/btf44dc9.aspx)?

Comment: i dont understand what u mean? can u explain it to me plz?

Comment: What is the exception you are getting?

Comment: just my page doesn't redirect to any page.didn't show me any exeption

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will make a couple of daring assumptions for the "lack of exception", but let's give it a try:

1. You have [JIT debugging disabled for script in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8kf6y2a%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
2. You have [disabled debugging in Internet Explorer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241741%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Referring to the questions real topic, you are probably binding the data source to your `GridView` in the `Page_Load` event (check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12450217/674700)).

Inside your user control (or wherever you are binding the data to the GridView), you have to check for `!Page.IsPostback` before binding the GridView to your data source:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    gridView.DataSource = new[] { new { Id = 1, Value = "test" } };
    gridView.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: i just test in Firefox not IE,i make a sample in another project and it was work, but in my project doesn't work.    :((